# How can I build a Lego rubik's cube?

Tags: building

How can I build a LEGO Rubik's cube, I have 2 of them, and I've built them several times, but how can I build a LEGO Rubik's cube.

Comment: There is a proposed set on the LEGO Ideas site [here](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/112517) of a LEGO Rubik's cube that is sturdier than the smaller one in @jncraton's answer. Of course, you can customize it however you wish. The center uses LEGO Technic to make it sturdy. Go to the updates tab and scroll down for instructions.

Answer (score 15):

There seems to be basically two choices. You can either build a larger version than the traditional cube, or you can build something that doesn't stay together very well.

There's a nice example of a small cube on [Sebastians Sand's Brickshelf](http://www.brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi?f=226538):

[image: small cube]

While this looks like it would work, I can't imagine that it holds together through many rotations.

If you are willing to build something a bit larger, there are some [good examples available](http://users.skynet.be/maarten.steurbaut/Rubik_Cube.htm), but it looks like it gets fairly complicated.

[image: larger Technic cube]

Answer (score -2):

Here is a video on how to stick LEGO bricks on to a Rubik's cube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrbBZ4EytHs

You're welcome.

Comment: This video shows you how to make a Rubik Cube look like LEGO rather than actually being made out of LEGO.

Comment: Downvoting because the question asks about how to *build* a rubiks cube out of lego, not how to make a rubiks cube look as though it was built out of lego...